# Image to browser height, width proportional

Tags: jquery, image

I have a JS script as:

```
window.onresize = function() {
var height = $(window).height(); 
var width = $(window).width(); 
$(".item").height(height);
}
```

and the relevant HTML is:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Example Text</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It works well in that the item div is scaled to browser height. But what I want is for the image to be set to that height as well, and scaled width-wise. I realise there may be cropping on the left/right of the image - that is fine, but I need to image to basically fill this div.

So the image height is determined by the browser height, and then the width is proportional so it fills the browser width as well. Does that make sense? Am sure I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.item {
    background: url(path/to/image/goes/here.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, here's a suggestion. Instead of using `window.onresize`, try using the following (since you're using jQuery):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('item').height(h).width(w);
});
```

Comment: Thats fine, as it resizes the image in proportion, but it doesnt fill the height of the item container (achieved by determining window height)

Comment: @Palemo Wait, so you want both the `img` and `.item` elements to occupy 100% of the window's width **and** height?

Comment: I want the div container .item to be browser height (via jquery) - done and then I want the image within this container to fill both width and height. I can get it to fill the area, but it isnt proportional meaning it stretches the width.

Comment: @Palemo Hmm, well I'm out of ideas. As far as I know, making the image 100% of the browser width **and** making it proportional at all times isn't possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58849/discussion-between-srikarg-and-palemo).